# Expressing "<verb>-ingly", where "<verb>" happens to be transitive

Tags: verbs, adverbs, participles

Suppose I have this intentionally strange-sounding (and perhaps ungrammatical) sentence.

> Finante faru ĝin!

Maybe even this one.

> Faru ĝin! Sed finante!

That is to say, "Do it, but finishingly so!" or "Do it, and finish the task!". Beware that this is **only a question about grammatical correctness** and **not about good practice**. If I were to actually communicate the idea, I would not say it like that.

That aside, in my question, the adverb here does not necessarily need to pertain to "fini", but any transitive verb. Why transitive? Because I feel like the "finante" in the two sentences are missing an object, unless it shares it with the "faru", and I am curious about what the rule here is, when the adverbized verb is transitive.

Unrelated to transitivity, the "-ant" in the "finante" implies the present tense, when I am using the volitive mood. Dunno what to do about that one without using a neologism.

Speaking of which, if I really had to come up with something, here's something wild, even stranger-sounding, and probably should not be used in actual conversation.

> Finentece faru ĝin.

With a "-entece" ending analogous to "-antece" and "-ontece", as in words like "estontece". This way, it would no longer seem to require an object (or subject complement in the case of "estontece"), and would no longer imply the present. But, again, I know this is probably kind of abusive of the language, but hey, it's fun!

Comment: I must admit, that I have hard time to understand what you're trying to say, what kind of expression you have in mind. So I comment only the part I understood, "Do it and finish the task". Here "finish" means to do the task up to the completion. "Faru ĝin ĝis kompleto!" or "Faru ĝin kaj kompletigu ĝin!".

Comment: Can you try to write in English what you want to convey in Esperanto? Maybe with a bit of context? I don't understand what you mean and the title of the question doesn't help a whole lot either.

Comment: I don't think English has an easy way to express what I want to say. The closest thing I can elpensi is "finishingly do it" or "Do it! Finishingly!". I avoided English examples because this is not really something I would say in English.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an easy way, just an understandable one. Sadly the sentences in Esperanto really don't make much sense. `finante` means `while finishing` (what?). There is way to say what you want to say, and we can help you find it but first we have to know what it is you want to say. It seems you found a structure, built a sentence and tried to assign meaning to it ...

Comment: Please [edit] your question post to contain an actual question (other than the rhetorical "Why transitive?" that you answer yourself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The active adverbial participle forms (*a/i/onte*) are best understood as *frazekvivalentoj*, i.e. as replacements for subclauses. The tense is always in relation to the *ĉefverbo* (predicate).

- *Finante faru ĝin!* : While finishing do it.

Being a transitive verb the participle form also requires an object. As far as I can see there is none. To summarise, the sentence as such doesn't make sense.

Comment: Would "finantece" be an overly contrived word? Particularly as an analogue to "estantece".

Comment: FWIW, I must confess that I have never seen the word "estantece" or "finantece". Furthermore I understand the parts, but I don't understand what the whole means.Neither word is in Tekstaro and rapid googling reveals only what appear to be Latin and Spanish sentences.

Answer (score 2):

```
Eat the meal but finish it = Tamen finu manĝi ĝin
                           / Manĝu tamen finu
                           / Manĝu tamen ĝisfine.
Do it and finish the task = Faru kaj finu la taskon
```

`Fini` can function as help verb, being followed by a verb. Which seems to relate to your V-ingly question. For lack of good examples, I have added some variations one sees in living language.